# How to deal with variable weights on invoicing?

Tags: shipping, invoice, quantity, delivery

Imagine that a webshop is selling bulk paper and that a customer wishes to purchase 50,000 sheets. However, when the supplier completes their production the final quantity may actually be 54,000 sheets.

This can affect weight and therefore the cost of delivery.

The webshop will invoice on final quantity/weight so sometimes the invoice quantity may vary to the order and order acknowledgment.

I was wondering if anyone had any advice or experience of dealing with such a challenge?

I thank you greatly in advance for your kind help.